# URL Scheme for linking to an item in the TV App

Tags: ios, tvos

Is there any to link to a particular item in the TV App on iOS or tvOS?

I know I can open the TV app with `videos://`, and that you can link to an item in the iTunes app with something like this: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/id1063466898`.

One would think the id's would be the same, but after lots of trial and error I can't find a structure with `videos://` that links directly to a show or movie.

The reason is that the TV app links to multiple ways to watch an item (be it rent, purchase, Netflix, Hulu, CBS All Access, etc), while linking to the iTunes Store only shows iTunes options (obviously).

[Edit]

So it looks like the following works: `https://tv.apple.com/us/show/amazing-stories/umc.cmc.15p55n2osur6c56uam2gxhye3`

And actually the `/amazing-stories` element is optional. But I can't figure out how to convert iTunes id's to TV app id's.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems like the IDs for the TV app are totally different from iTunes. The following will launch the tv app and go directly to The Force Awakens:

```
https://tv.apple.com/us/movie/star-wars-the-force-awakens/umc.cmc.61i3yveu7xby4chfkqved19ka
```

You can see it's a totally different id from the iTunes URL:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/id1063466898
```

Doesn't seem like Apple doesn't supply an API for searching the TV library. But frankly searching the domain with DuckDuckGo seems to find everything I've thrown at it.